# How to use -recurse with Move-item in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have created a simple powershell script in which it copies files from a source folder to a destination which is having same directory structure.

```
$source_path ="C:\Akash\Working\Source\*"

$backupPath="C:\Akash\Working\Dest"

copy-Item $source_path $backupPath  -Recurse   -EA "silentlycontinue"
```

It works fine, but when I try it with move-item in place of copy-item, it throws me an error:

```
Move-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Recurse'.
```

Someone please suggest here...

Answer (score 12):

The [Move-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849852.aspx) cmdlet doesn't have a `-Recurse` switch.

It is not required, because it already copies all the child items:

> The Move-Item cmdlet moves an item, including its properties, contents,
>   and child items, from one location to another location.